# Do the PNG images need to be added in cdnjs?

Tags: fine-uploader

we are [cdnjs](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs) team. We want to update [fine-uploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader) library in cdnjs. But we don't know whether the **PNG** images in `placeholders` folder need to be added or not. Could you please help me confirm it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to be able to access and use the placeholder images, then yes, they must be hosted as well alongside the JavaScript, CSS, and icon images.

Note that Fine Uploader is in the process of transitioning to an MIT license. That will likely be scheduled for version 5.9.0. I suspect this will have some impact on your work.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.